# Use vba to cut blocks of text from msword and save with a unique name

Tags: file, variables, macros

My macro cuts a block of text from a large file, & pastes it into a new Word file. What additional vba code can save this file with a name extracted from its own text?
Here is portion of my text file, just two entries, with my Macro to cut and paste following

```
<html>
<head>
<title>679: GREEN, John</title></head>  
<body><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td width="200" align="LEFT" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4">   
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">ID</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">679</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#CCFEFE">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Surname</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">GREEN</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Given Name/s</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">John</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#CCFEFE">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Age</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">73Y</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Born</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">00/00/1852</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#CCFEFE">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Died</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">06/09/1925</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Buried</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">07/09/1925</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#CCFEFE">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Section</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">23\12</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#CCFEFE">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Section</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Died in Xxxxxxxx, Victoria, Australia. See next photo <a href="679b.html">679b.html.</a></font></td></tr>  
</table></td>  
<td><img align="left" src="Sec 23 Gra 12.jpg"></td>
</body>
</html>  

<html>  
<head>  
<title>680: GREEN, Susan (nee WHITE)</title></head>  
<body><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td width="200" align="LEFT" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4">   
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">ID</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">680</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#CCFEFE">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Surname</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">GREEN (nee WHITE)</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Given Name/s</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Susan</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#CCFEFE">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Age</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">80Y</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Born</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">00/00/1856</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#CCFEFE">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Died</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">01/12/1936</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Buried</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">02/12/1936</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#CCFEFE">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Section</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">23\12</font></td></tr>  
<tr bgcolor="#CCFEFE">  
<td valign="top"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Section</font></td>  
<td valign="top"><font face="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Died in Xxxxxxxx, Victoria, Australia. See next photo <a href="679b.html">679b.html.</a></font></td></tr>  
</table></td>  
<td><img align="left" src="Sec 23 Gra 12.jpg"></td>
</body>
</html>  "
```

Here's my code that doesn't give me the file name I'm looking for - for the first block above, that would be 679b.html, and the next 680b.html.

```
Sub Create_JPEG_HTML_file_name()  
Dim i As Integer  
Dim FoundName As String  
Dim Records As Integer  

Records = 0  

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory  
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting  
    With Selection.Find  
        .Text = "<HTML>"  
        .Replacement.Text = ""  
        .Forward = True  
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue  
        .Format = False  
        .MatchCase = False  
        .MatchWholeWord = False  
        .MatchWildcards = False  
        .MatchSoundsLike = False  
        .MatchAllWordForms = False  
    End With  
    While Selection.Find.Execute = True  
    Records = Records + 1  
Wend  
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory  

For i = 1 To 2 ' Should be “For I = 1 To Records” i.e. total count for records, but I’ve set it to 2  
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting  
    With Selection.Find  
        .Text = "</html>"  
        .Replacement.Text = "</table>"  
        .Forward = True  
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue  
        .Format = False  
        .MatchCase = False  
        .MatchWholeWord = False  
        .MatchWildcards = False  
        .MatchSoundsLike = False  
        .MatchAllWordForms = False  
    End With  
    Selection.Find.Execute  
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1  
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend  
    Selection.Cut  

Documents.Add Template:="Normal", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0 ' Blank Word document opened  
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault) ' Block of text pasted to newly opened Word document
```

ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
"F:\Cemeteries\Private\html photos\images"

```
   Selection.Find.ClearFormatting  ' The open Word document now requires a name to be saved, so I tried this...  
    With Selection.Find  
    .Text = "<title>" ' Finds start of file name to be assigned to our opened Word document  
    .Replacement.Text = ":" ' Finds the end of the file name  
    .Forward = True  
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue  
    .Format = False  
    .MatchCase = False  
    .MatchWholeWord = False  
    .MatchWildcards = False  
    .MatchSoundsLike = False  
    .MatchAllWordForms = False  
    .Execute  
   End With  

    Selection.Find.Execute  
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1  
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend  
    Selection.Copy ' Copies file name  

   FoundName = Selection.Text  
   FoundName = Trim(FoundName + "c.html") 'Should give our current open file the name  

ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=FoundName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText, _  
   LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword _  
   :="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _  
   SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:= _  
   False, Encoding:=1252, InsertLineBreaks:=False, AllowSubstitutions:=False _  
   , LineEnding:=wdCRLF  
ActiveWindow.Close  
Next i ' Gets next block of text
```

Any suggestions????

My search for and designation of a name for my text file didn't work.